# Ping em PHP + Apache2 Debian

Tags: php, mysql, ip

Bom dia,

Consegui em pesquisa na internet fazer o script abaixo funcionar como o que eu precisava,mais ainda falta um detalhe,ai eu to conseguinte pingar em uma maquina,como eu poderia fazer para ser uma lista de maquinas,sem que eu precise repetir os comandos para cada maquina ?

A minha idéia inclusive seria fazer essa integração com banco de dados mysq,que ai daria um select trazendo os ip's cadastrados lá.

Segue o código:

```
<html>
<head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="5">

        <title>PAINEL DE MONITORAMENTO</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/simplex/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/simplex/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/datatables.css">
        <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap/js/datatables.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='container'>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PAINEL DE MONITORAMENTO   |</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div><a href="#"></a><img src="on.png" alt="ATIVO">  ATIVO
     <a href="#"></a><img src="off.png" alt="INATIVO">  INATIVO</div>
 <br>
 <?php
function ping($host)
{
        exec(sprintf('ping -c 1 -W 5 %s', escapeshellarg($host)), $res, $rval);
        return $rval === 0;
}

$host = '192.168.0.77';
$up = ping($host);
?>
<div class"container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <?php
         echo"<div class='list-group'>";
           echo"<a href='#' class='list-group-item active'>IP: $host </a>";
           echo"<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>NOME:</a>"; 
           echo'<a href="#"  class="list-group-item">STATUS: <img src="'.($up ? 'on' : 'off').'.png" alt="'.($up ? 'up' : 'down').'" /></a>';
         echo"</div>";
         echo "<br/>";
         ?>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <?php
         echo"<div class='list-group'>";
           echo"<a href='#' class='list-group-item active'>IP: $host </a>";
           echo"<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>NOME:</a>"; 
           echo'<a href="#"  class="list-group-item">STATUS: <img src="'.($up ? 'on' : 'off').'.png" alt="'.($up ? 'up' : 'down').'" /></a>';
         echo"</div>";
         echo "<br/>";
         ?>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
        <?php
         echo"<div class='list-group'>";
           echo"<a href='#' class='list-group-item active'>IP: $host </a>";
           echo"<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>NOME:</a>"; 
           echo'<a href="#"  class="list-group-item">STATUS: <img src="'.($up ? 'on' : 'off').'.png" alt="'.($up ? 'up' : 'down').'" /></a>';
         echo"</div>";
         echo "<br/>";
         ?>
     </div>
   </div>
  <br>
</body>
</html>
```

@rray : 
  Eu fiz pelo while mais esta trazendo somente o primeiro resultado,poderia ver se estou fazendo algo de errado:

```
<?php
require_once('conexao.php'); 
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT srv_ip AS IP, srv_nome AS NOME_SERVIDOR FROM servidores");
   if (!$result) {
    echo 'Não foi possível executar a consulta: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
   }
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      $srv_ip    = $row["IP"];
      $srv_name  = $row["NOME_SERVIDOR"];


function ping($host)
{
        exec(sprintf('ping -c 1 -W 5 %s', escapeshellarg($host)), $res, $rval);
        return $rval === 0;
}

$host = $srv_ip;
$up = ping($host);

echo "<div class'container'>";
     echo "<div class='row'>";
       echo "<div class='col-md-4'> ";
         echo"<div class='list-group'>";
           echo"<a href='#' class='list-group-item active'>IP: $host </a>";
           echo"<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>NOME:$host</a>"; 
           echo'<a href="#"  class="list-group-item">STATUS: <img src="'.($up ? 'on' : 'off').'.png" alt="'.($up ? 'up' : 'down').'" /></a>';
          echo"</div>";
         echo "<br/>";
        echo "</div>";
         }
     ?>
```

Comment: Usa um array com um laço(while, for ou foreach).

Comment: @rray poderia ver por favor o complemento que coloquei na pergunta.

Comment: A chamada da função `ping()` e aquela div container também vão dentro do while.

Comment: Sobre o container eu removi do php,mais sobre a function não entendi bem,estou chamando ela errado ? porque eu preciso dela porque ela que faz o ping.

Comment: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ping($row['IP']); //...demais linhas`

Comment: 100% Obrigado. Fiz a alteração e seu certo.